# assign new dimension of length one

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have a DataArray for which `da.dims==()`.  I can assign a coordinate `da.assign_coords(foo=42)`.  I would like to add a corresponding dimension with length one, such that `da.dims==("foo",)` and the corresponding coordinate would be `foo=[42]`.  I cannot use `assign_coords(foo=[42])`, as this results in the error message `cannot add coordinates with new dimensions to a DataArray`.

How do I assign a new dimension of length one to a DataArray? I could do something like `DataArray(da.values.reshape([1]), dims="foo", coords={"foo": [42]})` but I wonder if there is a method that does not require copying the entire object.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987972/expand-dimensions-xray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `xarray.concat` to achieve this:

`da = xarray.DataArray(0, coords={"x": 42})`
`xarray.concat((da,), dim="x")`